# Quantum computing records (entangled qubits)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

What is the current **record** number of entagled qubits and how has this number been increased?

The latest result on stack exchange, which is 3 years old, reports 14 via 
this post: [How many stabilised qubits have been achieved in Quantum Computing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4226/)

in accord with this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6126?

For the purposes of this post, I'd prefer to leave the D-Wave computers out of the answers.

Comment: This is not an answer to either of your four specific questions, but this recent paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4848 achieved, if I am not mistaken, record single-qubit and two-qubit gate fidelities.

Comment: This is also not an answer to your question, and I couldn't (yet) find a reference with more than 14, but Rainer Blatt himself told in a lecture I've seen that they can hold up to 40 qubits in the trap. I haven't asked him how many of them they can entangle with good enough control, but I'm sure he'd answer "If I want to, all of them.". Let's say he is a very incisive person... I'd try searching in his publications (the most recent involving circuits might be promising).

Answer (score 2):

This link at the Institute for Quantum Computing, Waterloo website mentions that the current world record is shared by IQC and MIT for 12 qubits.

The link mentioned in the question talks about 14 qubits in the GHZ type entangled states, it is actually a 14 qubit register which has been achieved, I still think the number of entangled qubits for Quantum computing purposes is just around 12! (I asked a friend at IQC).

https://uwaterloo.ca/institute-for-quantum-computing/quantum-computing-101#When-quantum-computer